# Sockets to trigger functions on receiving data

Tags: c, sockets

Is it possible to run the C socket library in non-blocking mode, and trigger a function on receiving any data? The function will then evaluate the received data and decide the flow of control in the program.

It would be very helpful if you could mention some references.

Comment: C socket library? Do you mean POSIX sockets? What OS are you working with?

Comment: yes, I am using C POSIX library in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using [libevent](http://libevent.org/) library that is possible.

First create an event base

```
struct event_base *ev_base = event_base_new();
```

Create and add that event for anything received on the socket

```
struct event *read_ev = event_new(ev_base, socket_fd, EV_READ|EV_PERSIST, callback_function_ptr, callback_function_arg);
event_add(read_ev, NULL);
```

At the end of the function dispatch events

```
event_base_dispatch(ev_base);
```